# Websites load testing using k6 from multiple IP addresses

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, k6

I am planning to do a load testing of an e-commerce website, where request I want to simulate from 100 IP addresses. New to k6 any input will help. Even input for jmeter will also help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--local-ips` k6 option to make k6 use multiple source IPs: https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/options/#local-ips

Comment: This option requires you to have multiple NCs (Network Cards), it wont work on a normal laptop or computer where you only have 1 NC